# Position of an observation in a column within a group

Tags: r, data.table

Part of my data is as below:

```
    group       value
 1:     a  0.00000000
 2:     a  0.00000000
 3:     a -0.18586657
 4:     b -1.71540591
 5:     b  0.11086867
 6:     b -0.14350153
 7:     b  0.93055422
 8:     c  0.00000000
 9:     c  0.00000000
10:     c -0.03173145

library(data.table)
DT = setDT(structure(list(group = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", 
"c", "c"), value = c(0, 0, -0.18586657, -1.71540591, 0.11086867, 
-0.14350153, 0.93055422, 0, 0, -0.03173145)), .Names = c("group", 
"value"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame"))
```

For each group, I want to create a new dummy variable. This dummy variable equals 1 if its corresponding value (variable of column 2) has two zeros before it and itself is nonzero, otherwise it equals 0.

I tried many ways, but could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `shift` function twice along with a couple of `&`s to connect the three logical statements and then use the by argument to group by group. Note that the default for shift is lag, which is what we want here.

```
df[, value2:= as.integer(value != 0 & shift(value) == 0 & shift(value, n=2) == 0), by=group]
df
    group       value value2
 1:     a  0.00000000      0
 2:     a  0.00000000      0
 3:     a -0.18586657      1
 4:     b -1.71540591     NA
 5:     b  0.11086867      0
 6:     b -0.14350153      0
 7:     b  0.93055422      0
 8:     c  0.00000000      0
 9:     c  0.00000000      0
10:     c -0.03173145      1
```

to fill in any NAs that result from the first value in a group being non-zero, you could chain the result.

```
df[, value2:= as.integer(value != 0 & shift(value) == 0 & shift(value, n=2) == 0), by=group
   ][is.na(value2), value2:= 0]
df
    group       value value2
 1:     a  0.00000000      0
 2:     a  0.00000000      0
 3:     a -0.18586657      1
 4:     b -1.71540591      0
 5:     b  0.11086867      0
 6:     b -0.14350153      0
 7:     b  0.93055422      0
 8:     c  0.00000000      0
 9:     c  0.00000000      0
10:     c -0.03173145      1
```

Here, the second chain subsets on NA values and replaces them with 0.

---

As @Frank mentions in the comments, `shift` can accept vectors for its n argument. One method that uses this rather than two calls to `shift` above is

```
df[, as.integer(value != 0 & min(unlist(shift(value, n=1:2)) == 0, na.rm=TRUE)), by=group]
```

which does not result in NAs unlike the previous version.

Comment: I guess there's little reason to call shift twice instead of with `n=1:2`, maybe something like `DT[, !!value & !do.call(pmax, shift(value, 1:2)), by=group]` if you want to abuse conversion of numeric to logical... hm, I guess not `pmax`, but you get the idea.

Comment: The n argument of `shift` can take vectors? that is cool. I'll add a different method modifying this.

Comment: I think my way is wrong / needs to be reworked. For example `max(-1,0)` is zero.

Comment: Maybe wrapping shift in `abs`?

Comment: `shift` returns a list, so I guess not. Perhaps need some `Reduce` or a different function in the `do.call`. I don't know it off the top of my head.

Comment: OK. I'll take a look when I get a minute.

Comment: @lmo I was wondering if I could use the 'match' function to do this